# How much of the Citrus manga got adapted in the anime?

Tags: citrus

The [*Citrus*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=19398) anime came out at the start of 2018. However, the manga finished in August 2018.

Since the anime would have been in production for a while, we can't just assume that whatever chapter was released in December 2017 is what got into the anime.

So how much of the manga got adapted in the anime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, the anime episode titles that you can look up e.g. on [AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=12545) correspond rather well to the [manga chapter titles](http://citrus.wikia.com/wiki/Manga). They also don’t give many hints on the content so I don’t feel bad quoting them here. The following list is the manga titles and the corresponding episode (capitalisation adjusted):

1. Volume 1

   1. Love affair!? (episode 1)
   2. One's first love (episode 2)
   3. Love my sister ××× (not an episode title)
   4. Sisterly love? (episode 3)
2. Volume 2

   5. Love me do! (episode 4)
   6. Under lover (episode 5)
   7. No love (not an episode title)
   8. Out of love (episode 6)
3. Volume 3

   9. Love or lie! (episode 7)
   10. Love of war (episode 8 as *War of love*)
   11. Love is blind (not an episode title)
   12. Love is (episode 9)
4. Volume 4

   13. Winter of love (episode 10)
   14. The course of love (not an episode title)
   15. Love you only (episode 11)
   16. My love goes on and on (episode 12)

Having watched the anime and read up to volume 7, I can confirm that this correlation is sufficiently accurate; specifically the end of the anime coincides with the end of volume 4.

The manga chapter title source page lists 9 published volumes; at least a tenth is to be expected. So the anime adapted no more than 40 % of the manga.

Answer (score 4):

Episode 12 of the anime ended in with chapter 16 of the manga. However they changed the ending to make a bit anime original so you might want to check out chapter 16.

If you don't include extra chapters manga ends at chapter 41.

10 volumes in total. Anime covered 4 volumes.